# Check if there exists a non contiguous subarray of K elements in an array of N elements whose sum is equal to a given value

Tags: algorithm

**Problem Statement**

The task is to check if there exists a non-contiguous subarray of K elements in an array of length N whose sum is equal to a given sum.

For e.g.,

```
Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
length of Subarray(K) = 3 
target sum = 7.
```

A non-contiguous subarray of length 3 with sum=7 is [1,2,4].

**Constraints:**

```
1<=n<=10^6 
1<=k<=100
```

**Output**

We have to return True if there exists a subarray with sum=TargetSum or False if this is not possible.

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are certainly more than 7 non-contiguous sub arrays:
1,2,4
1,2,5
1,2,6
1,2,7
1,2,8
1,2,9

That's 6 right there, then you can start at 2 and do the same thing. and keep going from there.

If you are allowed to go backwards [3,4,1] then you have even more sub-arrays